# Setting up an empty time series dataframe with monthly data for the FIRST day of the month

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

When I set up an empty pandas dataframe with

```
GWdates = pd.date_range('1/1/1940',periods = 900, freq='M')
Big_df= pd.DataFrame(index=GWdates)
```

I get this:

```
In [265]: df5
Out[265]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 900 entries, 1940-01-31 00:00:00 to 2014-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: M
Empty DataFrame
```

The dates are all the ends of the months, **how do I make it be the first of the month,** as in

```
DatetimeIndex: 900 entries, 1940-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014-12-01 00:00:00
```

Seems like `MonthBegin` would be what I am searching for, but I dont get the [docs for it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.10.1/timeseries.html). Seems like I must override something in the background, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `offsets.MonthBegin()`:

```
In [280]: import pandas.tseries.offsets as offsets

In [281]: pd.date_range('1/1/1940', periods=900, freq=offsets.MonthBegin())
Out[281]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1940-01-01, ..., 2014-12-01]
Length: 900, Freq: MS, Timezone: None
```

Or, actually, as the `Freq: MS` above shows, just [`freq='MS'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) will do:

```
In [282]: pd.date_range('1/1/1940', periods=900, freq='MS')
Out[282]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1940-01-01, ..., 2014-12-01]
Length: 900, Freq: MS, Timezone: None
```

Comment: `freq='MS'` seems to be exactly what I am looking for! Thanks. I knew it probably would be really trivial, but I couldn't find it myself.